Fast Forward Feature Selection with Weighted Importance for very high dimension (~14,000 features)
I'm working with a dataset containing 14,000 features, and I want to fit one model for each feature so that I can regress it using the other features. However, I believe only a small subset (around 10-15 features) will be relevant to each model.
My challenge is to find a feature selection algorithm that fulfills these criteria:

Forward Selection: I prefer an approach that iteratively adds features based on their importance, as this aligns with my expectation of a small, relevant subset.
Speed and Efficiency: The algorithm needs to be computationally efficient, especially since I plan to perform feature selection repeatedly. Ideally, it's optimized for repetitive use on large datasets (like how the graphical LASSO is an optimized version of the LASSO).
Weighted Feature Importance: Similar to the LASSO penalty, I'd like the ability to weight the importance of individual features during selection.

For the past two weeks, I've been exploring the Graphical LASSO. While it offers fast computation for high-dimensional data and allows weighted penalties, unfortunately, it's still too slow on my laptop. All thoughts and suggestions are very welcome.

You are searching for 10-15 needles in a haystack of size 14,000. Unless you have an absolutely enormous effect size, you will likely be chasing and "detecting" noise. So whatever you do, I would very much recommend you bootstrap your entire approach to get an idea of the variability involved. (Yes, this takes a while, but just do this for 10 of your 14,000 targets.)

In any case, I find it hard to believe that 10-15 features are relevant and 13,884-13,889 are irrelevant - more likely you will have tapering effect sizes, with tiny differences between the last feature selected and the first feature not selected. So I would very much recommend you either try to pare down your features beforehand based on theory (e.g., using PCA or similar).

Finally, why are you doing this in the first place? Is this for prediction (if so, how does this work when you want to predict each one of the features based on all the others - it seems like you have an "elephants all the way down" problem?) or inference (in which case you would need to correct for this feature selection, which will not be trivial)?
